# Join in sql server give me more rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

```
1. User

    id      language            program  status
    1       English/Spanish     CF/CA       1
    2       English             C           1
    3       Spanish             CF          1
    4       Greek               CA          1

2. Entry

   language             program
    English             CF
    English             C
    Spanish             CF
    Spanish             C
```

My requirement is to get the details from `User` table who has `language and program row in Entry table` and status = 1

```
    eg:- User ID 1 has language English/Spanish and Program CF and 
User id 2 has language English and Program C and user 3 has 
spanish and CF so only 3 rows will be retrieve
```

I am using below query

```
select u.*
from user u inner join
Entry e
on( u.language like '%'+e.language+'%'
and u.program like '%'+e.program+'%')
where [status] = 1
```

I am getting below result. I know some pblm in joining I am not able to fixit.
Pls help

```
User id     language           program     Status
1           English/Spanish    CF/CA        1
1           English/Spanish    CF/CA        1
1           English/Spanish    CF/CA        1
1           English/Spanish    CF/CA        1
2           English            C            1
3           Spanish            CF           1
3           Spanish            CF           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    select u.*
from [user] u where  exists ( select 1 from 
Entry e
where (u.[language] like '%'+e.[language]+'%'
and u.program like '%'+e.program+'%')
and [status] = 1)
```

Comment: You can try above query which i post

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be to add `group by u.id, u.language, u.program, u.status`
as you only select data from the user table.

But you could also consider to redesign your tables, so you maybe get a better solution for this problem, for example create tables for languages and programs.

[edit: fixed typo]

Comment: i can't change the schema..but ur suggestion is pretty simple i forget group by option..